# How to limit an array field in javascript object to a certain length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this may a simple problem but I have a the following javascript object:

```js
const categories = {
    title: 'cat1',
    contents: [
        {
            name: 'cont1'
        },
        {
            name: 'cont2'
        },
        {
            name: 'cont3'
        }
    ]
}
```

How can a transform this `categories` object so it has only 2 `contents` element as an example?

```js
const transformedCategories = {
    title: 'cat1',
    contents: [
        {
            name: 'cont1'
        },
        {
            name: 'cont2'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you creating this array or are you getting this as response from somewhere?

Comment: maybe `const transformedCategories  = {...categories,contents: categories.contents.slice(0,2)}`

Comment: limiting the length from the API is not supported as `contents` here refers to a subdocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways to do it:

```
const transformedCategories = {
  title: categories.title,
  contents: categories.contents.slice(0,2) // you can also use splice here
}
```

Another, slightly cheeky way:

```
const contents = [...categories.contents];
contents.length = 2;
const transformedCategories = {...categories, contents}
```

Comment: Second example is just one line: `categories.contents.length = 2;`

Comment: Definitely! Although, that would modify the original object, which could be undesirable depending on the use case. Hence my recommendation to avoid modifying the original properties.